# Azure Eventhub: de-mux and aggregate events from all partitions of eventhub using IEventProcessor

Tags: azure, akka-stream, azure-eventhub

I have 1 eventhub with 2 partitions, I want to aggregate my data for a minute and save that data to database, I am using IEventProcessor to read events from the eventhub.

I am able to save data to database as it is, but when I aggregate data, I get 2 entries per minute instead of 1. I think the reason is the IEventProcessor runs twice, i.e each time for a partition in eventhub.

Are there any ways I can achieve aggregation of streaming data for a minute while reading from eventhub and then save to the database? (I can't use stream analytics, since I have data in protobuf format.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Azure IoTHub React](https://github.com/Azure/toketi-iothubreact) Java and Scala API, it provides a merged *reactive stream* with events from all EventHub partitions.

From your perspective you'll see only one stream of data, regardless of the number of partitions in EventHub, and you can select a subset of partitions too if you need.

[These samples](https://github.com/Azure/toketi-iothubreact/blob/master/samples-scala/src/main/scala/A_APIUSage/Demo.scala) show how the API works, it should make your task very simple. You need to define your "Sink" which is going to be a method writing events to a database, and link the provided "Source", something like:

```scala
val eventHubRecords = IoTHub().source(java.time.Instant.now())

val myDatabase = Sink.foreach[MessageFromDevice] {
  m ⇒ MyDB.writeRecord(m)
}

eventHubRecords.to(myDatabase).run()
```

Here are the [configuration settings](https://github.com/Azure/toketi-iothubreact/blob/master/samples-scala/src/main/resources/application.conf), checkpointing supports Cassandra and AzureBlob.

Note: the project is named after Azure IoT, however you can use it for EventHub, let me know if you have any question.

Comment: I use c#, I am not sure if this has c# equivalent?

Comment: @RadhikaBhala no, there's no current equivalent in C#. It would be possible to recreate the same tool using [Akka.NET](http://getakka.net), if you are willing to. If you are looking for a C# solution, have you considered using the lower level [EventHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient) client, establishing two connections and merging the events in the application?

Comment: My Eventhub has data in both the partition

`{"Time":"2017-05-14T06:41:26.2630811","PowerDC":5642.45849609375,"AccelX":0.011730000376701355,"AccelY":0.0048699378967285156,"Pressure":9.0,"PartitionKey":"718a6ebf-aea0-4b4b-bb68-9ad5e9697164"}`

Do you have recommendation on how to read for a minute and average data from both the partition grouped by partitionkey,  using lower level eventhub or any other option:

@Devis Lucato

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stream Analytics and it's Group By clause. As long as all the rows are unique it won't summarize them. You can then push that output onto another Event Hub for your IEventProcessor to handle, or write it directly to storage.

Comment: Documentation on Group By here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835023.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I am using protobuf format data, so I cant use streaming analytics

Comment: You can't do it directly in he Hub, you'll need something external like the above option. You could also use Storm, but that could be overkill.